# How to clone PC without Intel Optane to a PC with Intel Optane

Tags: boot, bsod, clone

I am a computer tech and have cloned PCs for years, even wrote my own software to do it. For a few years now, I've ran in to boot issues after cloning from a non Intel Optane PC to an Intel Optane enabled PC. In the past, there has always been an option in Bios to disable the Intel Optane by setting the SATA mode from Raid to AHCI. However, recently this option has been disappearing from BIOS and now when I clone to an Intel Optane enabled PC, I get a blue screen saying "inaccessible boot device". I have done the obvious such as trying various cloning software, disabled secure boot, recreated the UEFI boot partition and always try to find an option in BIOS to disable Intel Optane or set SATA mode to AHCI. So I am looking for any solution or suggestion for when you need to clone to an Intel Optane enabled PC with no option to disable it? I am out of ideas and quite often doing a fresh install is just not an option. Any suggestion on cloning software that supports this or a way to alter the restore to support Intel Optane would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most disk imaging programs support the ability to apply an image of a disk from one device to a dissimilar device, sometimes this feature is a premium or optional feature. Without additional details this question is difficult to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just finished a Windows 10 to an HP with Intel RST clone. Go to intel.com and download the "Intel® Rapid Storage Technology Driver Installation Software with Intel® Optane™ Memory (11th up to 13th Gen Platforms)" zip file for Intel RST drivers (currently f6vmdflpy-64.zip). Unzip it.  Copy the F6\VMD\f6vmdflpy-x64 folder to your Windows Boot Media. Boot from it. Choose Install not Repair.  If RST is your issue, you won't see the drive. Choose add driver, then browse to the f6vmdflpy-x64 folder and load the drivers.  Do not install Windows.  Close the install without rebooting.  Choose the Repair option. Launch a command prompt and run

```
dism /image:c:\ /add-driver /driver:d:\f6vmdflpy /recurse
```

Where c:\ is the Windows drive and d:\ it the install media.

If you install the drivers successfully, it will reboot just fine.